# ¿Como separar elementos de un RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

he implementado un RecyclerView correctamente pero los elementos estan completamente juntos entre si, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para separarlos como si fueran un MarginBotton o algo paracido, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, empezando por la modificación de item.xml, también podrías usar CardView para darle un toque de separación visual más fuerte.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

Por último si no deseas complicarte mucho y estás usando la librería de support 25 para arriba, entonces puedes usar el dividerItemDecorator:

```
 DividerItemDecoration mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
             mLayoutManager.getOrientation());
     recyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);
```